# Android Browser Activity Fails To Display Certain Images?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using a web view to load a facebook page and it's been working until recently when facebook started requiring an anti-bot security check every time the page is visited. The problem is the image used to display the captcha text won't load inside the webview. For a second there's a small icon of a broken image which disappears quickly. I've tried it on the built in browser and the image displays fine, so I was wondering if anyone had a clue as to what I could do to fix this issue.

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        m_WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        m_WebView.setWebViewClient(new LocalWebViewClient());

        m_WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        m_WebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        final String finalUrl = tempUrl;
        m_WebView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                m_WebView.loadUrl(finalUrl);
            }
        });
```